# Project weelchair vertic university

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20050088024](https://www.google.com/patents/US20050088024)
good afternoon,

I am a student of the master course integrated in mechanical engineering at the University of Minho and I am completing my final project, which has as its theme the development and design of a vertical and ergonomic chair.

From the research that I have been developing, it is necessary to place anti-sealing systems on the chair, so that the user does not slip during the change of position.

This patent idealizes what I need for the backrest system. How can I use this kind of mechanism without copying this mechanism? What differences does it have to have in order not to infringe the patent law? As I verify other patents that are based on this patent, I would like to see how it works.

Thank you,

Leonel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually now a granted US patent, [US 7296856](https://www.google.com/patents/US7296856). If you do implement all of the features of any one of the claims in the US, you may well be infringing this patent. However, in broad strokes, if your product does not implement all of the features of any one (or more) of the claims, you would not be infringing.

However, given you are at a Portuguese university, you may be interested to know that the European equivalent ([EP 1522298](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP04256248)) was deemed to be withdrawn on 20 March 2007. There are therefore no rights in respect of this particular application in Europe (though there may of course be other relevant patents).

Comment: "if your product does not implement all of the features of any of the claims" is potentially ambiguous. It might be interpreted (wrongly) to mean all the features of all the claims. Perhaps you could emphasize you mean even just one claim.

Comment: @EricShain Good point: fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Can you follow slide No 87 & 88.Link: https://www.unipi.it/ricerca/phdarchivi/edizioni/phd2012/Dispense-d/golzio/how_file.pdf

Comment: While the linked document is a nice overview of the patenting process, you should summarize what answers the question here and then provide the link as backup. Also, the slides are not numbered so it is tedious to find what you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks Eric Shain. Infringement (The Hamburger case) is presented in the slide no 87 which help you to understand the claims of your to US 7296856. (pdf link doesnt have slide number but its present when open with Mozilla)

Comment: Again, to make your answer useful to the community, you should edit the answer to summarize an explanation and then link to the outside resource. Although links can be helpful, answers should be useful standing on their own. Since the link comes up at slide 1 and there aren't page numbers, you could tell the user to search for "hamburger".